# How to show that a problem is ill-posed

Tags: well-posedness

I was searching around here for a while but I didn't find any discussion on this topic. We know that a problem is well-posed when

1. There is a solution (existence),
2. There is only one solution (uniqueness),
3. The solution depends continuously on the data for the problem (stability).

I suppose that as soon as either one of these conditions is not satisfied, the problem becomes ill-posed. Now as I was reading about this topic I came across a statement that said

> To show ill-posedness of a given problem you must find a family of solutions with unity $L_{2}$ norm of the initial data whose growth rate is unbounded, e.g. backward heat equation.

But what does this statement say exactly? In particular, what does "*family of solutions with unity $L_{2}$ norm of the initial data*" mean? How do we see this for the backward heat equation for instance?

For example, as an exercise they want you to show that the problem

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t) &= \alpha \frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}}(x,t) + \beta \frac{\partial^{4}u}{\partial x^{4}}(x,t), &x\in\mathbb{R},\; t>0,\\[3mm]
u(x,0)&=\sin x, &x\in\mathbb{R},\\[3mm]
u(x,t)&=u(x+2\pi,t), &x\in\mathbb{R},\;t>0
\end{align}
$$

($2\pi$-periodic Cauchy problem) where $\beta>0$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ is ill-posed. I made an attempt on a solution, but I am not sure what my conclusions become (or if they are right):

Make the Fourier ansatz $u(x,t)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\hat{u}_{k}(t)\cos(kx)\implies \hat{u}_{k}(t)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}u(x,t)\cos(kx)dx$.

Thus we have $\hat{u}_{k}(0)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}u(x,0)\cos(kx)dx=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin x\cos(kx)dx \stackrel{?}{=}0$ for all $k$.

Space derivatives of ansatz become

$$\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}}(x,t) = -\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k^{2}\hat{u}_{k}(t)\cos(kx)$$

and

$$\frac{\partial^{4}u}{\partial x^{4}}(x,t) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k^{4}\hat{u}_{k}(t)\cos(kx)$$

Insertion into PDE yields

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\partial \hat{u}_{k}}{\partial t}(t)\cos(kx) &= -\alpha \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k^{2}\hat{u}_{k}(t)\cos(kx) + \beta \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k^{4}\hat{u}_{k}(t)\cos(kx).
\end{align}
$$

Comparison of coefficients and with initial conditions given by $\hat{u}_{k}(0)$ we obtain the solutions

$$
\begin{align}
\hat{u}_{k}(t) = \hat{u}_{k}(0) e^{(-\alpha k^{2} + \beta k^{4})t}.
\end{align}
$$

We see that this inserted into the ansatz implies that the solution $u(x,t)$ grows unbounded for any $\alpha$ and $\beta>0$, but the ansatz or initial conditions $\hat{u}_{k}(0)$ seem off (everything just becomes zero?). And have I implicitly showed that the problem is ill-posed? Is the $L_{2}$ norm of the initial data at unity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation is fine. You have discovered data $u(x,0)=\cos(kt)$ whose solution becomes unbounded. Now consider initial $v(x)$ having unit initial norm and combine them into initial data
$$U(x,0)=v(x)+\epsilon \cos(kt)$$
You can make $\epsilon$ small enough that the initial data remains as close to unity as you wish. But, however small you make $\epsilon$, you can choose $k$ to make the solution at time $t$ as large as you like. This is ill-posedness.

Comment: I think I understand, but you mean $u(x,0)=\sin(kx)$ right? And why is the $k$ parameter introduced, to construct a family of initial data? And also what is the importance of $v(x)$? Why can we not just choose $v(x)=0$? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I can choose $v(x)$ so that it satisfies the required initial condition, and then I can *perturb* it so that it still satisfies the initial condition (to any accuracy that you wish), but grows without limit. To do that I must choose $k$ large enough. $\sin$ or $\cos$ doesnt matter